# Ionic + firebase error conection in login

Tags: cordova, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication, cordova-plugins

i was trying to work with native google map of ionic to add map in my porject, after install the `ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-googlemaps --variable API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID="YOUR_ANDROID_API_KEY_IS_HERE" --variable API_KEY_FOR_IOS="YOUR_IOS_API_KEY_IS_HERE"` and `npm install --save @ionic-native/google-maps`the app start with some bugs so i toke the decition of remove the plugin, after remove the plugin for some reason i get this error from firebase `auth/network-request-failed` on the emulation of the device when i try any kind of firebase auth to login the user, but when i run the project with `ionic serve -l` doesn´t show me any error. Any idea what could be happen.

note: if i install the ionic native plugin of google map the auht error is gone but the bug is back so i have no idea what can i do in this case.

just in case

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "ctgmobileApp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "4.4.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.4.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.4.3",
    "@angular/core": "4.4.3",
    "@angular/forms": "4.4.3",
    "@angular/http": "4.4.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.4.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.4.3",
    "@ionic-native/core": "4.3.2",
    "@ionic-native/native-page-transitions": "^4.3.3",
    "@ionic-native/screen-orientation": "^4.5.2",
    "@ionic-native/social-sharing": "^4.3.3",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.3.2",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^4.3.2",
    "@ionic-native/toast": "^4.4.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "^2.1.3",
    "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.4",
    "com.telerik.plugins.nativepagetransitions": "^0.6.5",
    "cordova-android": "^6.3.0",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^1.1.4",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^1.1.16",
    "cordova-plugin-screen-orientation": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^4.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.2.3",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.1",
    "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": "^5.2.1",
    "cordova-plugin-x-toast": "^2.6.0",
    "cordova-sqlite-storage": "^2.1.0",
    "es6-promise-plugin": "^4.1.0",
    "firebase": "^4.6.2",
    "ionic-angular": "3.7.1",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "^2.2.1",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.19.1",
    "promise-polyfill": "^6.0.2",
    "rxjs": "5.4.3",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.0.1",
    "typescript": "2.3.4"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-sqlite-storage": {},
      "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": {},
      "ionic-plugin-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {},
      "com.telerik.plugins.nativepagetransitions": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-x-toast": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "android"
    ]
  }
}
```

**auth.services.ts**

```
  public async loginUsers(email: string, password: string): Promise<any> {
    return await this.fireAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
  }
```

**login.component.ts**

```
  public login(): void {
    this.userProvider.loginUsers(this.user.email, this.user.password).then((response) => {
      //
    }, (error) => {
      if (error.code == 'auth/wrong-password') {
        this.alerts('Login Fail', '<br><br>Cuenta de correo o contraseña incorrecta.');
      } else if (error.code == 'auth/user-not-found') {
        this.alerts('Login Fail', '<br><br>Correo electronico incorrecto o no existe.');
      } else if (error.code == 'auth/network-request-failed') {
        console.log(error)
        this.alerts('Error de conexion', '<br><br>Verfique que cuenta con una conexion a internet.');
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, trying to find a solution i finally found something, the bug i was getting with the cordova nativa google map was at the moment of push a page, at the moment of push the new page the app go back to last page and stuck in that page without been able to do something, i found that there is a small conflict between `cordova Native Google Map` and `Native Page Transitions` that cause that behavior on the application, so i just remove the Native Page Transitions and reinstall the cordova Native Google Map, doing this the bug is gone and the auth with firebase is working again.

Honestly i think this is only a temporary solution. Still have no idea why the installation and removal of the `Native Google Map` plugin cause a conflict/error/problem with angularfire2/firebase, but so far i could find any other solution.

i post this in case somebody else have this same problem or similar to this.